# using re.finditer (or another function) to find a str and parse out following data in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm attempting to build my first program in Python 3.4 that aims to parse out forensically interesting data from the setupapi.dev.log file in windows XP (a text based log file that stores it's data in ASCII).

I'm currently using `re.finditer` to identify the location of "VID" but need to specify that its the following 5 characters that I am interested in.

So far my code looks something like this:

```
import sys 
import re

file_path = sys.argv[1]
file_pointer = open(file_path)
data = (file_pointer.read()

find_vid="VID"
v = re.finditer(find_vid, data)
for each in v:
  print('%02d-%02d: %s' % (each.start(), each.end(), each.group()))
```

results:

```
188275-188278: VID
188785-188788: VID
...
```

Is there a way of using this function so that I can parse out the text that follows VID within the text file?

Comment: Provide sample text file. Can't say what needs to be done without seeing the data itself.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the `5` characters after a pattern, you can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) with a group:

```
>>> s = '123VID foo 456VID bar '
>>> re.findall('VID(.{5})', s)
[' foo ', ' bar ']
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group.

If you want to stick with `finditer`, the syntax will be slightly more complex because you have to extract the group manually:

```
>>> [m.group(1) for m in re.finditer('VID(.{5})', s)]
[' foo ', ' bar ']
```

Comment: @SergeBallesta Because of "(or another function)". But I added the `finditer` version nontheless.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your response will have a play with it and see what the results are!